# Convert Xaml to html5

Tags: html, xaml

Is it possible to convert WPF XAML (containing content such as image, video, animation etc) to HTML5 so that it can be rendered using html player on any device? Is there any readymade component/tool  available to accomplish it?

Comment: This project might be one to watch, though it's not finished yet: http://fayde.wsick.com/home.aspx

Comment: The above link doesn't work. Anyone found a solution to this? I tried CSHTML but that is not very straight forward and doesn't work for most xamls (ones which have resources, references).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your code on the web, it would be best to use silverlight in my opinion.